# Не могу определить тип разъема в ноутбуке

Tags: электроника

[image: Вот этот разъем, напишите пожалуйста как он называется]
Открыл ноутбук и пытаюсь понять что это за разъем

Comment: Вот бы еще вид сверху был, может там какая подсказка кроется в виде маркировки

Comment: В IT индустрии без преувеличения десятки тысяч разъемов. Каталоги разъемов для конструкторов по 1000 страниц. :-( А на этом сайте сидят не конструкторы, а программисты. Вам надо на сайт, где конструкторы сидят, может там что-то Вам подскажут.

Comment: На нем же написано 1620. Это M.2 1620 для твердотельника

Comment: @PavelZabelin я тоже подумал про м2 ) но не особо силен в его стандартах, ключах там разных, не стал ничего особо утверждать )

Comment: @RifmaMan если бы неделю назад не вставлял такой, то же бы не стал утверждать. Они есть M.2 1620 и M.2 2230